# Not sure what this notation means

Tags: notation, normed-spaces

I have the following equation attached. I know that the double lines means that I need to find the Euclidean distance between $P$ and $P'$ however I am not sure what the upper and lower value of $2$ mean. I think that the upper value of $2$ means that I should perform a power of $2$ after finding the Euclidean distance, but what does the lower value of $2$ indicate that I should do?

[image: Notation]

Comment: The subscript $2$ is just to emphasize *which* of the norms we were referring to as there are many choices available.  See [$p$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#p-norm) on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value $\|x\|_2$ is defined as the **[Euclidean norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm)** of the vector $x$, i.e.

$$\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle}=\sqrt{x^Tx} = \sqrt{x\cdot x}.$$

Note that every norm also induces a metric, and the metric, induced by the Euclidean norm, i.e. the mapping $$(x, y) \mapsto \|x-y\|_2$$

is called the Euclidean metric.

Comment: So, would the square root cancel out since I have an upper value of 2?

Comment: @Jason Yes, $\|x\|_2^2 = x^Tx$.

Answer (score 3):

The Euclidean norm is a specific example of a family of norms indexed by non negative integers. For $\mathbb{R}^n$ define the norm $||\cdot ||_p$ by

$||x||_p = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$.

Then we get the Euclidean norm for $p=2$.